# Failure getting snapshot on UI Testing

Tags: ios, testing, xcode-ui-testing

I'm trying to select a cell from table view in UI Testing with that code:

```
let clientTable = app.tables
XCTAssert(clientTable.cells.count > 0)
clientTable.cells.element(boundBy: 0).tap()
```

The problem is when I'm run that test on device and even in simulators I have this error:

```
Assertion Failure: <unknown>:0: Failure getting snapshot Error Domain=XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=9 
"Error -25204 getting snapshot for element <AXUIElement 0x7f9ddea00e10> {pid=22751}" 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error -25204 getting snapshot for 
element <AXUIElement 0x7f9ddea00e10> {pid=22751}}
```

What could be happening?

Comment: Did you try it in Xcode 9 beta 6, Apple has changed the way they fetch elements for UITesting, The simplest solution is to reduce the data in your tableView.

Comment: So, I can't do a test with huge data isn't it?

Comment: That's true, but i did not test with Xcode 9 yet so can not confirm.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097285/what-causes-error-25204-getting-snapshot-for-element-during-ios-app-ui-test